# Replace asterisk in derived column in SSIS 2008 r2

Tags: ssis

I've tried

```
replace(myfield,"/*/","")
replace(myfield,"/*","")
replace(myfield,"[*]","")
```

nothing is working.....it's replacing the whole field as if '*' were a wild card.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the replace in a derived column transformation, yes? `REPLACE(myfield,"*","")` works fine for me.

[image]